# HTML form to GET two variables from a PHP page

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I've been working for several hours trying to get this to work properly. The page I have a form on is `/index.php?action=pagename`. I have a form that needs to get a variable from the following `/index.php?action=pagename&thing=something`. My HTML form going like this:

```
    <form role="form" action="pagename" method="get">
           <input type="text" name="thing">
    </form>
```

This form is located on `/index.php?action=pagename` and I want to get `&thing` from that URL.
Any ideas?

The problem I'm having is that when the form is submitted, the URL redirects to `index.php?thing` instead of staying on `index.php?action=pagename`.

Comment: "This form is located on /index.php?action=pagename and I want to get &thing from that URL. " - `thing` does not exist in `/index.php?action=pagename`

Comment: the value that will be passed to `$thing=thisvalue` is available as the value of the input within the form.

Comment: When you add `&thing` to `index.php?action=pagename` new content is loaded based on `&thing`. The purpose here is to search for `&thing` using a form so users can load the content with adding `&thing` manually.

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact problem I'm having. I don't know why I'm being down-voted so harshly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be having some trouble with `<forms>` in general and not just PHP so here is an overview:

```
<!-- the action is where you want to send the form data -->
<!-- assuming THIS code is the index.php file then we want to send the data to ourselves -->
<!-- the method is GET so it will be directly accessible from the URL later -->

<form action="index.php" method="GET">

    <!-- add a hidden value for pagename -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pagename">

    <!-- the name called "thing" will be appended to the URL and it's value as well -->
    <input type="text" name="thing" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['thing']) ? $_GET['thing'] : ''); ?>">
    <br>

    <!-- click this button to submit the form to itself -->
    <!-- once this has been submitted then you can retrieve the URL value with $_GET as you can see above -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I used this, the result was the URL redirecting back to `index.php?thing='result'`

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't generally use `method="GET"` but I think the updated code should work now

Comment: Thanks for thinking outside the box, you rock!

Comment: You're welcome, don't let the downvotes discourage you because I can definitely remember when I struggled with `<form>`s as well so hopefully you stick with it because web development overall has a bright future.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the PHP-variable `$_GET['thing']` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute of the form element is the target script which will be called on submit. If blank it will be the current script which is showing the form. You also can only give url parameters beginning with ?.

```
<form role="form" action="?action=pagename" method="get">
       <input type="text" name="thing">
</form>
```

Exerpt from php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/de/tutorial.forms.php

> One of the most powerful features of PHP is the way it handles HTML
>   forms. The basic concept that is important to understand is that any
>   form element will automatically be available to your PHP scripts.
>   Please read the manual section on Variables from external sources for
>   more information and examples on using forms with PHP. Here is an
>   example HTML form:
>
> **Example #1 A simple HTML form**
>
> ```
> <form action="action.php" method="post">
>  <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
>  <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
>  <p><input type="submit" /></p>
> </form>
> ```
>
> There is nothing special about this form. It is a straight HTML form
>   with no special tags of any kind. When the user fills in this form and
>   hits the submit button, the action.php page is called. In this file
>   you would write something like this:
>
> **Example #2 Printing data from our form**
>
> ```
> Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
> You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.
> ```
>
> A sample output of this script may be:
>
> ```
> Hi Joe. You are 22 years old.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Basic script I made to get the variables from the URL:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["action"]) && isset($_GET["thing"])) {
    $action = $_GET["action"];
    $thing = $_GET["thing"];
    echo $action .PHP_EOL . $thing;
}
?>
```

This will output the following for the URL `/index.php?action=pagename&thing=something`

```
pagename
something
```

Though you should probably learn how to use forms properly first.